# date in sql query with asp.net program

Tags: c#

On the server, the date format is `mm-dd-yyyy`. On my local machine, the date format is `mm/dd/yyyy`.

I have the following code:

```cs
DateTime FrDate, Todate;

string yy = "2020";           

string mm = "04";

string dd = "01";

DateTime.TryParse(mm + "/" + dd + "/" + yy, out FrDate);
```

And then I am trying to run this query:

```
select * from helpdesk_tranactions where compl_date `= '" + FrDate.ToShortDateString() + "'
```

This is working fine when I run on my local machine, where the date format is `mm/dd/yyyy`.
However, when this code is deployed to the server, the same query is not working (since the date format is `mm-dd-yyyy`).

The error I get is:

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
> The statement has been terminated.

How can I write this query in such a way that it will work regardless of the system date formatting?

Comment: use parameters and DateTime directly

Comment: Is your asp.net server and sql server different `cultures`?

Answer (score 3):

Noooooooo! If you're worried about string formats for SQL date values something has already gone horribly wrong.

The column in your database should be a `Date`, `Timestamp`, or `DateTime` rather than `varchar` field, and if that's true *there is no human-readable format!* The data is *binary*. What you see is a convenience shown to you by your management tool or connection library. If you're not using one of the date types for the column column, you should *fix the schema*, because it really is **broken**.

Once you have confirmed or fixed the column so you know it is a `DateTime` value, you should also be using `DateTime` variables in the C# code. And once you're doing that, the correct way to include those values in a query looks like this (assuming MySql because of the backtick, but you should also tag the question with the correct database engine):

```cs
string sql = "select * from helpdesk_tranactions where compl_date = @compl_date";
using (var cn = new MySqlConnection("connection string here"))
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, cn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@compl_date", MySqlDbType.DateTime).Value = FrDate;
    cn.Open();

    // ...

}
```

Notice this assigns the `FrDate` field directly to the query parameter. *There's no conversion in your code to worry about.*

This technique is also the best and only truly safe way to avoid certain [other types of problem](https://xkcd.com/327/) with sql.

Comment: Hmm... the error message looks more like it came from Sql Server, but again: until you tag the question with the correct database engine, we can't really know.